# The color style in XCODE 4.0 isn't working?

Tags: xcode

I already upgraded XCODE from V3.5 to 4.0, but the color style isn't working now, the color of variable name and function name etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist in Xcode.  There are a number of  color keys in there.  Just search for "color".  Maybe one of those somehow got munged?  Alternatively, you can try deleting the com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist file.  Xcode should recreate it when it starts up.